# using the window.location.href in angular template(.html file) giving an error

Tags: angular

I am using `window.location.href` in angular template and it is throwing an error saying `cannot read property of undefined 'location'`. any help is very much appreciated.

something.component.html

`<div [class.selected]="window.location.href.includes('something')">...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

something.component.ts

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) public document: Document) { }
```

something.component.html

```
<div [class.selected]="document.location.href.includes('something')">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why mix DOCUMENT and other JS stuff when Angular already provides you with what you need. I assume you have the Router configured so try this.

Apply this when in component

```
//something.component.ts
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

extract class SomethingComponent implements OnInit {
  routeCheck = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeCheck = this.route.url.includes('something')
  }

}

// something.component.html
<div [ngClass]="{'selected': routeCheck}">...</div>
```

Outside of the component, let's say in menu

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";

//...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  urlCheck = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.urlCheck = event.url.includes("something");
      });
  }
}
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6zao2a?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: the context is different. i am using that condition on a menu to display and hide few option.

Comment: Ah ok, it's still doable, but bit different, see the extended answer